# Подписи на осях графика aChartEngine

Tags: android, диаграммы

С помощью aChartEngine делаю CombinedXYChart:
[image: Пример]

Значения заполняю следующим образом:

```
CategorySeries barSeries = new CategorySeries(""); 
XYSeries lineSeries = new XYSeries("");
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
{
    barSeries.add(list.get(i).Text, list.get(i).Value);
    lineSeries.add(i, list.get(i).Norm);
}
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы на оси X под каждым столбиком выводился текст, который был указан в barSeries при заполнении? Желательно, повернутый на 45 градусов (ну или на 90).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавление подписей под столбиками и поворот на 45 градусов:

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRender = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
{
    mRender.addXTextLabel(i, list.get(i).Text);
}

mRender.setXLabelsAngle(45);
```